# Integrals of functions with compact support.

Tags: functional-analysis

let $f \in L^1(\Bbb{R}^{n})$ be such that for every non-negative $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function with compact support, $\varphi$, we have  $\int_{\Bbb{R}^{N}}f\varphi dm_{N} \  \geq{0}$. Show that $f \geq{0}$ almost everywhere on $\Bbb{R}^{N}$

Comment: The title seems to have an inequality mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The standard mollifier $f\ast\varphi_{\epsilon}$ of $f$ is such that $f\ast\varphi_{\epsilon}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}$, now passing to an a.e. convergence subsequence and you are done.